# Live in an EU country and pay taxes in your home country(non-EU)?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, ireland

I live and work in Ireland. Can I pay my income tax in my home country which is a non-EU country?

I've read all of these:

- [Is it possible to work in a country and pay taxes in another within the EU?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/99729/is-it-possible-to-work-in-a-country-and-pay-taxes-in-another-within-the-eu)
- [EU: Receive income in a country and pay taxes in another](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/109362/eu-receive-income-in-a-country-and-pay-taxes-in-another)
- [Taxes for citizen of EU country #1 living in EU country #2 and working from home for non-EU country #3?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/55644/taxes-for-citizen-of-eu-country-1-living-in-eu-country-2-and-working-from-home)

But my situation is different so, I asked a new question.

Also, I've seen this (which is for Eu-to-EU) but still, it is a concern to me:

> You should note that the tax rates in the two countries involved will most likely be different. If the tax rate in the country where you work is higher, that is the final rate you will pay - even if the tax paid in that country is offset against the tax due in your country of residence, or if your country of residence exempts you from any further tax.

[Source: https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/work/taxes/double-taxation/index_en.htm]

P.S:

- Considering I'm gonna live and work in Ireland for the rest of my life probably so, what are the suggestions? Isn't better(or maybe I have to) to pay income tax here in Ireland?
- The tax rate in my home country is lower than here, Ireland
- Both countries have signed the Double Taxation Agreement (which I'm not sure if double taxation agreement is related to my question/case or not)

Comment: Unless your unnamed home country levies taxes on expatriates then since you both reside and work in Ireland, its tax laws will apply.  But you should consult a tax accountant who is familiar with both Irish/EU tax law and your home country's just to be sure.  Such cases can be quite complex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While agreeing with @jwh20's comment that you should consult a tax accountant, a few notes to dispel what appears to be some missunderstandigns:

- In general, you do not get to chose which country/ies you must pay taxes to. Each country's laws define who is taxed, by which concepts, and how much. This is what goes.

  Of course, you may change which laws apply to you by changing your circumstances. If you moved to another country, then  Ireland would probably not claim anything you earned in that third country (it still could claim taxes due the period you were working at Ireland).
- Double taxation agreements apply when two countries may claim taxes on the same concept. If your country of origin does not claim that you owe them taxes for the money you got when working and residing in Ireland, it won't apply.
- In general double taxation agreements won't let you chose, either.
- And the purpose of double taxation agreements is just to avoid taxing you *twice* for the same event. So if Ireland claims $20 from you and another country claims $10 from you, it does not mean that you may chose to pay $10. It means that you will pay $20, and not $30.